# Использовать ли графический редактор для работы с Docker?

Tags: linux, git, docker, jetbrains

В IDE-редакторах JetBrains существует удобный графический модуль для работы с Git.
Я умею работать с Git, однако разницу в коммитах JetBrains показывает куда нагляднее.
Использовать ли что-то подобное для Docker?
Использовал ли кто? Насколько это будет удобно?

Comment: Если удобно работать через UI - работай!

Comment: ну так консоль это и есть UI для гит и докера. Но если через какой то инструмент удобно выполнять каждодневные задачаи, то почему и нет, ну если это только не sourcetree